# Access denied to run exe file in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i want to run exe file from stored procedure. But, output is 'Access is denied'.
how can i do? my sql query is as the following. It is just testing query

```
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'C:\Users\myo.minlin\Downloads\Firefox Setup Stub 33.1.1.exe'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because your **SQL-Server** process runs, if not specified other, not with your *myo.minlin* account. The account which started the process does not have permissions on the file you provided. This is good so, because the database should not be able to access your private files. There are three or even more possible solutions:

1. Move the file to a location where the SQL-Server has access to.
2. Make sure that the account on which the SQL-Server is running has the right permissions to execute your file
3. Launch the **SQL Server** process with the **myo.milin** account.

I do not reccommend solution 3. Solution 2 is also not reccommended if the file is in your home directory.

See [Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx#Default_Accts).

Comment: thanks for answer
yeah i can access files from 'D:', output is also fine showing information of exe file
but exe file doesn't run